# Creating a graphic component bean for NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have run into an issue when trying to create a JavaBean that works as a graphic component that you can drag and drop from the palette in the design view of NetBeans.

My problem is that if I make the bean from an empty container such as a JPanel, it works how that container is supposed to work in the design view, meaning that I can drag and drop other components from the palette into said container and the panel from the bean will **contain** them:

[Picture before adding new component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPooE.png)

[Picture after adding new component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMYu.png)

```
public class PutasBeans extends javax.swing.JPanel {


public PutasBeans() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 295, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The problem arises when I place any component such as a label or a button (anything, really) into the JPanel that I make the JavaBean from. When that is the case, anything I drag and drop into my custom component when using it from another project just moves the component aside and places itself next to it, as in:

[Before adding component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k94q3.png)

[After TRYING to add component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVQJU.png)

```
public class PutasBeans extends javax.swing.JPanel {


public PutasBeans() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

    jButton1.setText("Test Component");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(47, 47, 47)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 199, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(157, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

For the purpose of this example I've just used a JPanel but what I want to implement is a bit more complex, although not that much. I am guessing that it is some sort of JavaBean coding convention that I just haven't included, but the truth is that I can't seem to find almost any references to this topic online. Any help will be greatly appreciated. It just baffles me that it works just fine only until a new component is added. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears the panel is using the (default) `FlowLayout`. If the GUI view needs a different layout, set one.

Comment: I'm afraid changing the layout does not change the behavior of it, it still won't work as soon as there's a component inside the panel. As for the code, I'm about to add it. Thank you both!